# $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=2$, what is the value of $x$?

Tags: calculus

I came up with this little simple exercise, stating:

$x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$ infinite times is equal to $2$, find $x$.

As we're dealing with infinity, we can just separate the first $x$ and get $x^2=2 \implies x=\sqrt2$

But then I thought what if we change $2$ to $4$? Now we get $x^4=4 \implies x=\sqrt[4]4=\sqrt2$

Something went wrong, can someone explain?

Comment: If $x$ is large enough, the sequence $x, x^x, x^{x^x}, \ldots$ diverges.

Comment: And thus comes the question, $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}} = n \implies x=\sqrt[n]{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to define the expression is $$y = x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}} $$

$$\Rightarrow y^x = x$$

A slightly different definition is to define the sequence $a_0 = x$ and $a_n = x^{a_{n-1}}$. The problem is then to find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$$

It can be shown that the **interval of convergence** for the power tower is $$[e^{-e}, e^{1/e}]$$

Comment: Thank you, I have searched "power tower" and found lots of useful material on this topic, also some proofs of convergence :)

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E((2%5E(1%2F2))%5E(2%5E(1%2F2))))))))

Comment: @NarekMargaryan For your interest, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights

Comment: @ Ng Chung Tak, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $x_1=x$, $x_n=x^{x_{n-1}}$ converges only for $x$ inbetween $(1/e)^e$ and $e^{1/e}$ (including the ends of the segment) and the limit is never equal to 4.
S.G.

Answer (score -1):

$x^{x^{x^x\cdots}}=2\implies x^2=2$